# SqlDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet) returns {"The ConnectionString property has not been initialized."} after failed connection

Tags: vb.net, connection-string, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

I looked around for an answer to this issue, but couldn't find one (partly because there are so many instance where it isn't being set at all, and that isn't my problem).

I am adding some recovery routines around my SQL database interactions so that if I encounter an error (especially a deadlock or a momentary network failure), I can recover the transaction without data loss and continue the operation (this is for factory fixtures writing test data).

However, when I have two+ SQL calls inside the same routine, when the first one fails, even if it recovers successfully, the second one then returns:
{"The ConnectionString property has not been initialized."}

Here is the code I have been testing:

```
     If CheckAndRefreshSQL(False) Then
        Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = Nothing
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
        Try
            Dim sSqlQueryString As String = "EXECUTE dbo.usp_LogOn @LoginID = @UserName, @Password = @Pass" & AddedParms

            Dim sqlCmd As SqlCommand = Nothing
            sqlCmd = New SqlCommand(sSqlQueryString, m_SqlConnection)
            If mSqlTransaction IsNot Nothing Then
                sqlCmd.Transaction = mSqlTransaction
            End If
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", sUser_Id)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass", GetPasswordHash(sUser_Id, sPassword))
            da = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
            If FillWithRecovery(da, ds, False) > 0 Then
                ...
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            ...
        End Try
    End If
```

"FillWithRecovery(da, ds, False)" is one of the recovery calls, supplanting "da.Fill(ds)"

The problem here is that the "GetPasswordHash" routine also makes some of its own calls to SQL.  It uses the same class scope connection, but not the same SqlCommand.  If the SQL calls within the hash routine fail due to connection, they will attempt their own recovery.  If that recovery succeeds, the routine returns the correct data.  The ConnectionString in the class scope SqlConnection (m_SqlConnection) remains intact.  But for some reason, the ConnectionString in the local SqlCommand (sqlCmd) is now empty, and the "FillWithRecovery" call returns the above error.

This code works correctly when "GetPasswordHash" does not initially fail and have to recover.  This tells me it probably has something to do with the common SqlConnection between the two, but I can't figure out what.  I'm not manually making any changes to the connection itself.

Edit: As noted in the comments, it seems the SqlCommand.Connection object is 'Closed' after the Password routine executes its reconnection.  I could fix this by isolating the Connection objects from each other, or by reassigning the Connection property of the SqlCommand after a failed connection attempt, but what is it about the type of the SqlCommand.Connection object that causes it to act this way?  Why can it be Closed outside the immediate scope of my code, but not reopened?  It seems if it were being assigned by value, neither should be possible, and if by reference, then both should.  Am I implicitly passing a hard reference to the ClientConnectionId that remains static when the SqlConnection itself is reopened?

Comment: The error message tells you whats wrong.  No where in that code is the connection for the DA passed set

Comment: Doesn't the CommandType for that Command object need to be set to StoredProcedure?

Comment: @Plutonix The Adapter is picking up the Connection from the Command object.

Comment: @LarsTech Apparently not.  It works without setting the type.

Comment: The error tells you that your m_SqlConnection object hasn't been initialized.  You should put your connection objects into a local using block anyway and *not* make it a global variable like that.

Comment: @LarsTech m_SqlConnection has been initialized.  It is populated when it is passed to New SqlCommand() and it is populated when it comes back from GetPasswordHash().  But I'm seeing now that the state of the Connection object in sqlCmd is "Closed" after the password routine recovers itself.  The connection must be getting refreshed by the network failure, and invalidating the connection used to instantiate SqlCommand.  Agreed on the 'using', but this is part of a much bigger, automatically generated library, and that would require a major architecture change.

Comment: `It is populated when it is passed to New SqlCommand() `  Not with the code you posted it's not.  You aren't passing a connection object to GetPasswordHash, so it looks like it has it's own connection.   If that routine is using the same connection object, well, then you are seeing the problems caused by global variables.  You have spaghetti code.

Comment: While I concede the pitfalls of global scope, this is unfortunately not an architecture I designed, nor one I am in a place to make changes to at this juncture.  I could likely fix this specific issue by switching to local connection models for this routine, but I would still like to understand why the Connection object acts the way it does.